# Matplotlib legend shows some unexpected codeline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was learning the matplotlib library and hence tried to show 2 lines on 1 graph to represent a machine learning model. The issue is with the legend. There is some code line in legend. I don't know how to remove it. Could someone please help removing it?

```
alldata=plt.plot(x,y,'o')
l1 =plt.plot(x_new, model1(x_new),'r',linestyle='dashed',linewidth=4)
l2 =plt.plot(x_new, model2(x_new),'g',linewidth=4)
plt.title('no. of bench employees needed for new projects over last 5 years')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('employees/month')
plt.xticks([W*12 for W in range(6)],['year %i'%w for w in range(6)])
plt.legend([("alldata"),(l1,"d=%i" %model1.order),(l2,"d=%i" %model2.order)], loc=1)
plt.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The above code produces this graph:

[image: graph by above code]

Comment: You may want to clarify your question, as you write "I don't know how to remove it", after referring to the legend, allowing for potential confusion in your meaning of "it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) documentation you'll notice that you called it with the wrong format. Citing the docs:

> For full control of which artists have a legend entry, it is possible to pass an iterable of legend artists followed by an iterable of legend labels respectively:
>
> ```
> legend((line1, line2, line3), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
> ```

So you'll need to pass in two tuples:

```
plt.legend((alldata[0], l1[0], l2[0]),                                # plots
           ("alldata","d=%i" % model1.order, "d=%i" % model2.order),  # names
           loc=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calls to `plt.plot` add `label='some unique label'` for each line. See https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html.

Answer (score 0):

You put those labels there yourself, using `(l1,"d=%i" %model1.order)`. Remove the `l1` from the label, to make it disappear.

```
plt.legend([("d=%i" %model1.order),("d=%i" %model2.order),("alldata")], loc=1)
```

or just

```
plt.legend(["d=%i" %model1.order,"d=%i" %model2.order, "alldata"], loc=1)
```

To keep the order, supply the handles as well.

```
plt.legend(handles=[alldata[0], l1[0], l2[0]],
           labels=["alldata", "d=%i" %model1.order,"d=%i" %model2.order], loc=1)
```

A different approach would be to specify the labels for the plots inside the plotting commands,

```
plt.plot(..., label="alldata")
plt.plot(..., label="label1")
plt.legend(loc=1)
```

This will automatically choose the labels for the legend.